# Split with Java a Python Dictionary String

Tags: java, regex, string

I Have Java program that invokes a Python script and takes the result which is a Python dictionary as a string. A result would be something like:

```
{'27': [], '10864': [u'8344', u'7769', u'7207', u'3735']}
```

I want to parse the result into two String tables the keys and the values as returned. In this example I want:

```
String[] keys >>>> ["27",'10864'] and

String[] values >>>> ["[]","[u'8344', u'7769', u'7207', u'3735']"]
```

I am trying to do it with regular expressions but I don't have much success. Can anyone give an efficient solution?

Comment: Why not return a JSON and parse it?

Comment: I write the python result in a dictionary and I use in Java something like
String puthonKeys = interpreter.eval("results").toString(); .Are you suggesting creating a JSON object from the dictionary, convert it to string and evaluate this from Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use regexes, here is [one approach](https://repl.it/IwVW):

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String strExample = "{'27': [], '10864': [u'8344', u'7769', u'7207', u'3735']}";
    
    // Initialize
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> values = new  ArrayList<String>();
    
    // Hacky regex parsing -- happy now???
    for (String component : strExample.replace("{","").split("][,}]")) {
      String kv[] = component.split(": ");
      keys.add(kv[0]);
      values.add(kv[1] + "]");
    }
    
    // Print
    System.out.println("Keys: ");
    for (String key : keys) {
      System.out.println(key);
    }
    System.out.println("\nValues: ");
    for (String value : values) {
      System.out.println(value);
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

This first splits on the closing bracket `]` and then the colon `:`

The output is as you desired ([run in repl](https://repl.it/IwVW)):

> Keys:
>
> '27'
>
> '10864'
>
> Values:
>
> []
>
> [u'8344', u'7769', u'7207', u'3735']

Note, you really should *not*:

1. use Strings for numeric keys
2. use regexes to parse JSONs
3. use anything like this code in a real system

Answer (score 2):

You can see the regex I have used [here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XO8DnM/1/).

Essentially the Matcher will run through your input and detect all matches of the regex. Then you use the .find method in a while loop to go through each match individually and extract the information.

You can use a regular array however in my opinion using an ArrayList is way more efficient if you are not sure of the size of the incoming input.

This code works for me:

```
     public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "{'27': [], '10864': [u'8344', u'7769', u'7207', u'3735']}";
    String pattern = "('([\w]*)': (\\[[u'0-9, ]*])?)";

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    //Find multiple matches in your input.
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(input);

    //Goes through each match individually.
    while (m.find())
    {
        keys.add(m.group(2));
        values.add(m.group(3));

    }

    //To display your keys and values.
    System.out.println("Keys: " + keys.toString());
    System.out.println("Values: " + values.toString());

}
```

Comment: Thnx for the solution but I dont have only number as keys values. I could have something "{ 'randomId': [] , ...... }

Comment: @PennT You could have an alphabetic character too? EDIT: I've changed my solution so it allows alphabetic characters.

Comment: @EduardoDennis thanks for spotting that and I appreciate the feedback.